# Spring @Transactional rollbacks when InvalidCredentialsException is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have the following code that saves failed login count to the database when user is not validated and then throws `InvalidCredentialsException`. However, `rollbackFor` causing rollback after saving the data to the database. I think there is a relation between `InvalidCredentialsException` and `JOSEException.class`, `JsonProcessingException.class` that are in the `rollbackFor` field. But I cannot see the relation and have no idea how to exclude the exception (`InvalidCredentialsException`) from rollback.

```
@Override
@LogExecution
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {JOSEException.class, JsonProcessingException.class})
public UserTokenDTO login(final LoginRequest request)
        throws JsonProcessingException, JOSEException {

    // code omitted

    if (user.isNotValidated) {
        setFailedLoginCount();
        throw new InvalidCredentialsException();
    }
}
```

So, should I change `rollbackFor` values?

Comment: `InvalidCredentialsException` is a `RuntimeException` which will lead to a rollback.

Comment: In your IDE, open `InvalidCredentialsException` and see what it `extends`. Follow that up.

Comment: Yes, I followed both exception and finally see that both of them go `Exception`. But as a result, most of the exception probably comes from `Exception`. In this scene what exception should I use in `rollbackFor ` and `if` block?

Comment: @M.Deinum Any idea?

Comment: The InvalidCredentialsException is a custom one ? It extends only Exception ?

Comment: Don't throw an exception, or use a new transaction.

Comment: The database update should be in a separate transaction.  If your login method only updates failed login count and nothing else, you could try removing the @Transactional annotation from it so the setFailedLoginCount() will update the database in its own transaction.  Otherwise you could use another spring bean with it's own @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) annotation that you call to update the database failed count.

Comment: @httPants Good points, thanks a lot